# check if multiple listed values are found in column VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i want make sure values PF, AD, FF are found in column A if all three are not found in column A show me error. my code is below pls help me.

```
Sub Check_All()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim c As String
Dim d As String
Dim e As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim mycell As Range
Set sht = Sheets("sheet4")
lastrow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
c = "PF"
d = "AD"
e = "FF"
Set mycell = sht.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Find(what:=c & d & e, LookIn:=xlValues)
If mycell Is Nothing Then

Else

  MsgBox "Error"
End If
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: you need to do three separate Finds

Comment: Or use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` three times.

Comment: @ScottCraner are you saying like this? Find(what:=c, LookIn:=xlValues),Find(what:=d, LookIn:=xlValues),Find(what:=e, LookIn:=xlValues)

Comment: @BigBen how would i write that out im very new to vba sorry

Comment: They would need to be three different lines with three different range objects into which the results are put then you would test if all three are valid ranges.

Comment: @ScottCraner something like this? Set mycell = sht.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Find(what:=c, LookIn:=xlValues)
Set mycell = sht.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Find(what:=d, LookIn:=xlValues)
Set mycell = sht.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Find(what:=e, LookIn:=xlValues)
If mycell Is Nothing Then

Else
MsgBox "Error"

Comment: No, you need three different range objects and test all three.

Comment: @scott Craner i got it to work Thanks all for your help!